# Unity Transparency Sort Axis doesn't work

Tags: unity-game-engine, transparency

First, My goal is render sprite objects as below.

[image]

So, I set Edit>Project Settings>Graphics>Transparency Sort Mode as "Custom Axis" and Transparency Sort Axis as (0,1,0).

But it only works in the Scene View. When I run play mode, the Transparency Sort Axis I set automatically return to the default value - I mean, Custom Axis + (0.49,-1,0.49). Then the objects' states in the play mode are as below.

[image]

I've been suffering from this problem over than a week... because as far as I remember, when I was much more unskilled Unity beginer and tried some tutorials, the setting I set in this way worked in the play mode without any issues.

I think maybe the reason is in the asset I imported because when I made a new project without any asset and tried exactly same procedures, it worked.(transparency sort axis didn't changed automatically during play mode). But I'm still not sure about this problem's reason yet and don't know how to fix it.

Could you please help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting it via code for both Graphics and Camera?

Comment: @derHugo I did. I added code to the script attached on the Main Camera, but it didn't work. But becaue I'm a beginner for Unity Engine, I could be wrong. Could you please give me some hints, or codes? –